# Using variables with export in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I would like to add some variables and echo commands in a [Makefile](https://github.com/mlcommons/inference_results_v2.0/blob/master/closed/NVIDIA/Makefile#L697). The section is:

```
.PHONY: run_harness
run_harness: link_dirs
    @mkdir -p $(LOG_DIR)
    @set -o pipefail && $(PYTHON3_CMD) code/main.py $(RUN_ARGS) --action="run_harness" 2>&1 | tee $(LOG_DIR)/stdout.txt
    @set -o pipefail && $(PYTHON3_CMD) scripts/print_harness_result.py $(RUN_ARGS) 2>&1 | tee -a $(LOG_DIR)/stdout.txt
```

and I want to add

```
.PHONY: run_harness
run_harness: link_dirs
    @mkdir -p $(LOG_DIR)
    ########
    @export WRK="test"
    @export startTime=$(date +%s)
    @echo $(WRK), $(startTime)
    ########
    @set -o pipefail && $(PYTHON3_CMD) code/main.py $(RUN_ARGS) --action="run_harness" 2>&1 | tee $(LOG_DIR)/stdout.txt
    @set -o pipefail && $(PYTHON3_CMD) scripts/print_harness_result.py $(RUN_ARGS) 2>&1 | tee -a $(LOG_DIR)/stdout.txt
```

But those export and echo don't work because I get `,` in the output which mean both `$(WRK)` and `$(startTime)` are empty. How can I fix that?

UPDATE:

The following change

```
@mkdir -p $(LOG_DIR)
export WRK="3d-unet"; \
export startTime=$(date +%s); \
echo $(WRK), $(startTime) ;
```

doesn't work due to this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line in a recipe is executed in a separate shell. You need to put all shell commands on one line, separated by semicolons (and possibly use line continuation with backslash newline for readability).
And you must reference shell variables with `$$name` (not with make variable `$(name)`). Note that *make* replaces a `$$` with a single `$` for the shell.

```
foo: bar
     export x=hello y=world; \
     echo "$$x" "$$y"
```

Comment: In fact I want to put another `entTime` after the `@set -o pipefail` commands and then print the difference.

Comment: @mahmood Well, that should work with something like `start=$$(date +%s); sleep 3; end=$$(date +%s); printf '%s\n' $$((end - start))`

Comment: What do you think about this command `WRK="test"; startTime=$$(date +%s); echo "$$WRK" "$$startTime";  $(PYTHON3_CMD) code/main.py $(RUN_ARGS) --action="run_harness"; endTime=$$(date +%s); WRKTIME=$((endTime-startTime)); echo "$$WRK" "$$startTime" "$$endTime" "$$WRKTIME";` I guess it is fine, but it isn't,

Comment: OK. `WRKTIME=$$(($$endTime-$$startTime))` fixes the problem.